# Javascript: Out of Memory

Tags: javascript, memory-management

I'm working on a script that fetches and then parses a large amount of XML documents. The relevant part of the code is shown below. (URL has been hidden for privacy. The asterisks in the code are not actually there, they are used for reference later in the question)

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var xmlDoc;
var chunk = parseInt(1, 10);
var subChunk = parseInt(0, 10);
var indvCount = parseInt(0, 10);
var total = parseInt(0, 10);
var max = parseInt(5000, 10);
var end = parseInt(chunk, 10) * parseInt(20, 10);
var start = parseInt(end, 10) - parseInt(19, 10);

function loadXML() {

xmlhttp.abort();
*xmlhttp.open("GET", "URL-GOES-HERE?start=" + start + "&end=" + end, false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml', 'Pragma', 'no-cache');
xmlhttp.send("");
while (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) { }
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
readXML();

}


function readXML() {

while (subChunk < 20) {
    *indvCount = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Value")[subChunk].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    total = parseInt(total, 10) + parseInt(indvCount, 10);
    subChunk = parseInt(subChunk, 10) + parseInt(1, 10);
}
chunk = parseInt(chunk, 10) + parseInt(1, 10);
subChunk = parseInt(0, 10)
end = parseInt(chunk, 10) * parseInt(20, 10);
start = parseInt(end, 10) - parseInt(19, 10);
if (chunk > max) {
    alert(total);
} else {
    loadXML();
}

}
```

When `chunk` is equal to approx. 5,000 or more, I get an `Out of Memory` error. The error usually refers to one of the asterisk'ed lines of code. Using Windows Task Manger, I can confirm that Internet Explorer's memory usage stays at about 6,000K, so I don't think I have a memory leak.

Does anyone know a way to prevent this?

Comment: What's the point of `+ parseInt(1, 10)`? Can't just say `+ 1`? Or `* 20` or `- 19` later on?

Comment: That really looks like an infinite loop to me... First, where is `subChunk` initialized? Then why are you calling `parseInt` on a value which should always be an integer already? (you're even calling `parseInt` on a literal integer?)

Comment: Could it perhaps be a parseInt(<? $someservervar ?>)

Comment: @r3c Sorry, all the variables are global and declared outside of this scope. I will update the question to include them. The loop always ends because chunk will eventually reach max and exit the loop. I was taught to ALWAYS use parseInt when dealing with integers, even when I don't need it. Is that causing a problem?

Comment: It's just slower, but if your value is already an int then parseInt will just give it back to you unchanged, so that doesn't explain your problem.

Comment: @r3c OK, I'll edit those out.

Comment: Using `parseInt` when you already have a number is only slowing your code down, since the browser needs to cast the number to a string, parse it, then return the number again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your readXML rewritten to eliminate useless cruft. Critique/questions after the code:

```
function readXML() {
    while (subChunk < 20) {
        indvCount = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Value")[subChunk].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        total = total + parseInt(indvCount, 10);
        subChunk++;
    }
    chunk++;
    subChunk = 0;
    end = chunk * 20;
    start = end - 19;
    if (chunk > max) {
        alert(total);
    } else {
        loadXML();
    }
}
```

1. Where do you initialize `subChunk`? The first time readXML is called, subChunk (if this is all of your code) will be undefined.
2. Ditto for `total`. Where does that get defined/initalized?
3. Ditto for `chunk`. Where does that get defined initialized?
4. Ditto for `max`. Where does that get defined initialized?
5. Note that I've eliminated all but one parseint. Unless you're doing all kinds of crazy int/string conversions in there, the ONLY place it would strictly be required is to turn your XML-retrieved string into a number for your `total` count.

---

Ok. how about re-writing like this... it'd still be using global variables (bad bad bad), but somewhat more correct and and efficient:

```
function readXML() {
    var values = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Value");
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
       total += parseInt(values[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
    chunk++;
    end = chunk * 20;
    start = end - 19;
    if (...) { ... }
}
```

Your code does a repeated getElementsByTagName call (expensive), accesses one value, then throws away everything else. Does another gEBTN() call, accesses another value, throws away the results, yada yada yada. A major waste of CPU cycles, memory, etc... With the above construct, you do gEBTN() **ONCE** then iterate over the results, pulling out all the relevant nodes.

Comment: I've edited the question to show where I defined my variables. Those should have been included originally; my bad.

Comment: I debugged your code, and `total += parseInt(values[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);` produces `total=NaN`